# How to export enhanced TIFF. images from r? dev off error

Tags: r, ggplot2, tiff

I'm trying to enhance the dpi of a TIFF. image that I've made with ggplot2 but it's not saving anywhere.

Here goes the code

```
    tiff("test.tiff", units="in", width=300, height=300, res=300)
        ggplot(DatLong) +
        geom_bar(aes(y = Percentage, x = Station , fill = Groups), stat = "identity") + 
        theme_minimal() + 
        scale_fill_manual(values = c("#003366", "#3366CC", "#993300", "#660099"))
     dev.off()
```

After that this error keeps appearing

> null device
> 1

I've tried shutting down R and start a new session but it keeps happening. It doesn't export the image file to the directory. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Cheers

Comment: Did you check the folder you used as `setwd()`?

Comment: You can use `ggplot2::ggsave` for an easier time

Comment: Yes, I checked using setwd( ) but there's nothing too @Duck

Comment: Thanks @RichardTelford, I will try that

Comment: That message you get isn't an error. It's just a message letting you know which graphics device is in use after running `dev.off()`. How are you running this code? Are you running interactively or from a script? If the latter you need to make sure to `print()` your ggplot object to actually render it. Is a file being created at all?

Comment: @MrFlick I'm running from a script. How do I `print ( )` my object in ggplot? Where should I put it? When I try to export the image from the plot window it works just fine, it creates a file but the resolution isn't great. I actually use this tiff command yesterday and it did created a file, but it's not working today, not even to create a file

Comment: This is one of the [R FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-lattice_002ftrellis-graphics-not-work_003f)s. You need `tiff(...); print(ggplot(...) + ...); dev.off()` where the `...` are the appropriate code chunks. The output will always go to your current working directory (`getwd()`) assuming there were no errors in any of the commands.

Comment: It worked! I also changed a bit the dimensions of the image. Thanks @MrFlick